# New career opportunity by former employer

Tags: job-offer

im after some advice on my situation

I started a new job with my current employer back in October last year, everything is ok although im not as keen as I was with this new job as I feel more of a glorified warehouse op than what the title suggests.

I left my old company because I couldn't see any progression there with the current situation of the people above me having served 15+ years and not likely to leave within the next 15 to 20 years and I was only a warehouse op and other team leader jobs in the manufacturing department were taken with no one really looking to leave and me not having any experience in those sectors.

Now comes my dilemma, my old boss has contacted me and has offered me the chance to return to my former company but this time as a manufacturing team leader for the Injection Moulding section after they had a surprise resignation, I met with my former boss and he outlined everything that I can do which would save them around 6-9 months worth of training and offered to send me on courses and training to learn the moulding machines if I accept.

This was also on top of a big increase of salary which will be an extra 33% on top of what I currently earn and will mean within 6 months my salary jumping a whopping 40% on what I used to earn 4/5 months ago.

Although I am keen to learn and take this opportunity with a company I like and know,

I don't want to make my new place of work and bosses feel like I have wasted their time and wondering if I should take the job opportunity.

Any advice out there for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's understandable you don't want to anger your current employer, at the end of the day **you need to do what's best for you**.

Clearly your former employer liked you enough to reach out to you directly about coming back to a leadership position with a pretty big salary bump. That doesn't happen every day, and it's certainly nothing to just brush off.

What you need to ask yourself is the same questions you asked at your former employer, but in regards to your current employer. Even if the prospects look good, will they pay as well as this new opportunity with your former employer?

Your current employer may get upset, but I'd hope any manager would understand an employee wanting to leave for such a large pay increase. It's also possible they could produce a counter offer, but don't expect this or even demand it.

Finally, get everything in writing from your former employer, ask them any questions you may have, and make sure you fully understand the duties of the position they're offering you in addition to the pay and other benefits. Since they're offering you a pretty sizable pay increase I don't get the impression they're trying to use you, but at the same time they do indicate you coming back would save them months of hiring and training someone else (definitely a plus for you in the grand scheme of things). Make sure the pay is appropriate for the job compared to others in the same or similar positions, but overall I'd say it sounds like you've got a pretty sweet offer.

Comment: Thank you, your comments have helped ease my mind on taking this new opportunity

Comment: Friendly reminder to mark the answer as accepted if you feel this is the best answer to your question. :D

Comment: @GreggPaddock No worries, it's why I mentioned it. Stack Exchange sites look for good questions and answers, and by marking the answer you feel is best you reward the person with an extra 15 points towards their rep score. Definitely keep coming back to see if you can offer your own answers to boost your rep. :D

Answer (score 1):

> Although I am keen to learn and take this opportunity with a company I
>   like and know, I don't want to make my new place of work and bosses
>   feel like I have wasted their time and wondering if I should take the
>   job opportunity.

Right.

Go for it, then.

You have to look out for yourself, and employees quitting, while unfortunate, is a known business risk. Your current employer will be fine. (They may not like you anymore and refuse to provide a reference, but ah well)

Do whats best for your career first.